# ASP.NET User Control instance is null when referenced on Page_Load on page code behind

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, pageload

I have a user control that I have written and have added to an ASP.NET page, and functions just fine. However, I am trying to reference a property in the that custom control from code behind, on Page_Load, but cannot, because the variable, which is accessible, for the instance is null.

Is this normal for user controls and Page_Load? And if so, how can I make a reference to the control's instance in order to access its public properties? This is something I need to do before the page is rendered, in order to initialize some variables.

Comment: You should be able to reference your User Control in the Page_Load method.  Please show your markup and your code behind.  In the markup example, please include the <%@ Register %> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably access your user control from the `Page_PreRender` event.

You can find more documentation about the [page life cycle in asp.net here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that I was registering my custom control incorrectly.

Correct Definition:

```
<%@ Register Src="PeriodControl.ascx" TagName="PeriodControl" TagPrefix="ucs" %>
```

Incorrect Definition:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ucs" Namespace="MyWebsite" Assembly="MyWebsite" %>
```

The only difference was to reference the ascx file directly instead of the control in the assembly. Go figure!?

Comment: What do you do if the user control is actually in an assembly (the ascx is in the DLL and not in the site).  I've typically used a web deployment project to compile all my commonly used user controls into a DLL.  VS2012 doesn't support that project type, but you can compile a site into an assembly and VS will read it.. but I can't figure out how to register is correctly so the controls on the user controls aren't null.

Comment: I'm not sure. If it referenced from a dll, maybe it will appear in your toolbox and you can drag it onto your page. Then VS will create the register tag for you :) That's all I can think of. Hope it helps...

Comment: I was struggling for 2 hours and finally I found your solution, it worked like a charm.

Comment: ReSharper seems to register user controls the "incorrect way" mentioned above by default when you use it's tips to locate user controls while typing....

Comment: It's strange but the "incorrect definition" worked for me until today. Then suddenly, due to an unknown reason, I got a NullReferenceException. The proposed fix worked and I noticed most `@ Register` in the project are using `Src`. Thanks for the tip.